# What can I do when Zune doesn't recognise that my phone is plugged in?

Tags: sync, zune, 7.x

I've plugged my phone in, and whilst I hear the USB chime on the PC, and the sync chirp on the Phone, Zune doesn't launch automatically -- If I launch Zune manually, it doesn't think the phone is plugged in.

How can I get Zune to see the phone again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if the drivers get corrupted - there is [a Fix-It app available from Microsoft](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9767934) that will check common causes, and attempt to resolve them for you.

Comment: Is there any solution for wp8 -> w8 connection? That link did not work on my w8 machine.

Comment: as I understand it, Windows Phone 8 does not connect with Zune, so it would be better to ask a new question specific for Windows Phone 8 - I've retagged this to make it clear this is for Windows Phone 7.x devices

Comment: Further investigation revealed that you're right: Zune does not apply for WP8.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of this issue has to do with the digital certificates the phone and Windows PC share. It can happen when trying to use more than one computer and not setting the sync relationship to guest on one of them. It also can happen when you are changing computers and didn't click "Forget This Phone" in Zune before changing.

Like Roland mentioned there is automatic Microsoft tool may help. If not follow these steps:

1. Go to Start, then type in CertMgr.exe in the search box, once you see it open it.
2. Locate the digital certificates that are named with the word named "Zune".
3. Delete *all of them*

Restart your Pc and phone, then connect to Zune via usb cable. You should be good to go, this process worked for me a couple times.