# Windows Lumia 920 not recognized by Zune

Tags: zune, nokia-lumia-920

I read [another question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/663/what-can-i-do-when-zune-doesnt-recognise-that-my-phone-is-plugged-in/664#comment2755_664) about Zune that does not recognize a Windows Phone device. Anyways, the solution provided there does not meet my situation, 'cause the fixIt does not start on my W8 machine.

Is there anywhere a FixIt program that works on Windows 8 environment?

My specs: Windows 8 Pro and Lumia 920 WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 devices are not meant to be synchronized using Zune. Just put your music on the phone by using MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). You will see your Lumia 920 in the Windows Explorer.

If you really want to use an extra application, you can use this: http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/de-de/app/windows-phone/0e0fbaf6-fd99-4046-b494-9ce469ae3009

Comment: Originally my problem is that I am registering my phone to dev purposes and that registering tool claims I haven't registered device to MarketPlace and furthermore that registration thing let me to suggestions about installing Zune first. Where that registration should be done withOUT Zune?

Comment: I think you can do it in visual studio, but development questions are off topic for this site.

Comment: You can unlock your phone without Zune if you use the correct SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Phone Registration)